# Shopware 6.5.0 : Get the current page ID using a event subscriber

Tags: plugins, shopware6

I would like to know how to retrieve the current loaded page ID in the event listener like StorefrontRenderEvent or PageLoadedEvent. Alternatively, is there another method to fetch the ID of the loaded page in the twig template? I am using Shopware 6.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically you can [listen to the `CmsPageLoadedEvent`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events).

```php
class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CmsPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onCmsPageLoaded',
        ];
    }

    public function onProductsLoaded(CmsPageLoadedEvent $event)
    {
        var_dump($event->getResult()->first()->getId());
    }
}
```

In the twig template you may get the id of `cms_page` like this:

```
{% set cmsPage = page.landingPage ? page.landingPage.cmsPage : page.cmsPage %}
{{ cmsPage.id }}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I require the ID of a page from the cms_page entity whenever it is loaded in the storefront. Could you please suggest the most suitable event for this purpose?

Comment: Hello, I have selected the code snippet in the twig template. It works perfectly for retrieving the CMS page ID. Thank you for your assistance. However, I'm wondering how we can obtain the category ID if it is a listing page.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like a "global page id" for storefront pages, as the id depends on the type of page that is being loaded, e.g. if it's a listing category page or a product detail page.

Depending on your actual use case it might be better to listen to the more specific `\Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPageLoadedEvent` or `\Shopware\Storefront\Page\Navigation\NavigationPageLoadedEvent` events, as they give you access to the rendered CmsPage and product or category respectively.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I require the ID of a page from the cms_page entity whenever it is loaded in the storefront. Could you please suggest the most suitable event for this purpose?